# What is the reverse proxy config used by AWS lightsail container service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, kestrel

I have deployed a .net web api via docker container into the aws lightsail container service which also gives me public url and SSL. The docker file runs `dotnet appname.dll` which runs the project as a kestrel web server.

1. When an instance of the service spins up, does aws lightsail run some kind of reverse proxy that directs requests to the kestrel? Or is kestrel directly exposed to the internet?
2. If there is a reverse proxy, then what is the max connections that it supports?